# How to calculate Ratio in SSRS 2010 if both values are in a group

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I have one dataset in SSRS. Values are in a group by Month and BookTotal.
I need to calculate Ratio which means particular value in BookTotal need to be divided by value for each month. So, Quoted/Submitted, Then Bound/Quoted and so son.
This is how it looks in Preview mode:

[image]

But everything in a group, so this is in a design mode:

[image]

I am trying to write an expression something like that:

```
=IIF(Fields!BookTotal.Value="Quoted",Fields!BookTotal.Value/IIF(Fields!BookTotal.Value="Submitted",Fields!BookTotal.Value,0),0)
```

But it gives me #Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are trying to divide two strings.

Your expression could be evaluted like this:

```
Quoted / Submited -> Two strings cannot be divided resulting in error.
Quoted / 0 -> any division by zero will cause error
```

> Note your expression say if Fields!BookTotal.Value = "Quoted" then
>   divide "Quoted" by "Submited" if Fields!BookTotal.Value = "Submited".

I think you need something like this:

```
=Sum(If(Fields!BookTotal.Value="Quoted",Fields!QuotedPremium.Value,0))/
 Sum(If(Fields!BookTotal.Value="Submited",Fields!QuotedPremium.Value,0))
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Still gives me #Error.  Warning 1 [rsAggregateOfMixedDataTypes] The Value expression for the textrun `Textbox22.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0] uses an aggregate function on data of varying data types.  Aggregate functions other than First, Last, Previous, Count, and CountDistinct can only aggregate data of a single data type.`

Comment: Thanks man, I got it right!
The only thing I got division by 0, and I cant come up with idea how to avoid NaN